# What is the unit of y axis in PerfMon png generated in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I monitor server metrics such as CPU(green), Disk I/O (red), Network I/O (pink) and Memory(blue) using PerfMon plugin & ServerAgent. I record the output to a csv file and generate graph using JMeterPluginsCMD.bat

I am able to see the graph plotted with legends for all these metrics but I do not know what is the unit of y-axis in the graph? How should I read say, the Memory usage in terms of the total %?

Also, is there a way to plot the graph (without running the test again) using the CSV output file so that y axis contains the % consumed rather than some high values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your configuration, when it comes to [Primary Memory Metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#total-1) the available values are:

Primary

- usedperc - relative memory usage in percents
- freeperc
- used
- free

[image]

First two return percentage usage, last two will give you the absolute values

I don't think it's possible to convert the values without re-running test because PerfMon Metrics Collector is querying the [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) for this or that particular metric and if you're requesting absolute values - you will get memory usage in bytes. JMeter doesn't know anything about hardware configuration of the monitored server so you will need to do the conversion yourself via [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) or equivalent

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thanks. I changed the y axis as percent and the graph is now more readable